# Find the arc length of a path

Tags: calculus, arc-length

I'm trying to solve the arc length for the following. $c(t) = (2, 6t^2, 4t^3)$ from $0\le t\le 1.$

I've checked on WolframAlpha and I get the answer $8\sqrt2 - 4$ but when I work it out I get $16\sqrt2$ where am I going wrong?

\begin{align*}
L&= \int_0^1 \sqrt{(12t)^2 + (12t^2)^2}\, dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \sqrt{144t^2 + 144t^4}\, dt\\
&= \int_0^1 12t\sqrt{1 + t^2}\,dt
\end{align*}

Then I do
$$ 8t\sqrt{(1+t^2)^3} = 16\sqrt2.$$

Comment: How did you get to $16\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $$\int_{0}^{1}12t\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$$
Use $u=1+t^2\implies \frac{1}{2}du=tdt$ to get $$\int_{0}^{1}12t\sqrt{1+t^2}dt=\int12\sqrt{u}\cdot\frac{1}{2}du=6u^{3/2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=4(1+t^2)^{3/2}\bigg\vert_{0}^{1}=4\cdot2^{3/2}-4\cdot1$$ $$=4\cdot2\cdot2^{1/2}-4\cdot1=8\sqrt{2}-4$$

Answer (score 0):

From $$\int_0^1 12t\sqrt{1 + t^2}\,dt,$$
let
\begin{align*}
u &= 1+t^{2}\\
du &= 2t\,dt.
\end{align*}

This yields
$$\int_{1}^{2}6 u^{1/2}\,du =4u^{3/2}\bigg|_{1}^{2}=4\sqrt{8}-4 = 8\sqrt{2}-4.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add a solution in the complex plane for contrast. Let

$$z=6t^2+i4t^3\\
\dot z=12t+i12t^2\\
|\dot z|=12t\sqrt{1+t^2}\\
s=\int_0^1|\dot z|dt=6\int_0^12t\sqrt{1+t^2}dt=6\int_0^1\sqrt{1+u}\ du,\quad u=t^2, du=2tdt\\
s=4(1+u)^{3/2}\big|_0^1=8\sqrt{2}-4
$$